# VBA Excel Cell Content Spacing Messed up when Parsed from HTML

Tags: html, excel, string-formatting, vba

I am having a problem with the spacing between strings when I parse data from an HTML. It's hard to explain, but I'll try my best. So my code runs through an HTML file and copies every table of data into just one cell within column A of excel. So when the code compiles, I have cells A1 to A10 (for example) filled in with a huge amount of data in each cell. What I want to do from that is scan through the cells and look for certain strings. The sample code is:

```
 sot = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "eggs and bacon")
```

the string I am looking for is multiple words with spaces. However, I have noticed that when the HTML data is parsed and transferred to excel, the spacing between the letters is messed up. For example, if I am in clicked into the cell and hit the left and right arrow cursors on the cell, the blinking cursor line sometimes ends up right in the middle of a letter, not BETWEEN two letters as it should be. This causes my code to not work because the number of spaces between strings cannot be correctly determined so the string cannot be found.

Therefore, sot returns a value of 0, when there is indeed an "eggs and bacon" string in the data.

Please let me know if there is anything I can do/if you've seen or had this problem before! I am getting very frustrated because I spent so much time making code that parses an HTML and a code that scans through my data looking for keywords, but it won't work just because the spacing gets messed up when going from HTML to Excel. Thank you so much.

Here is my code that parses the data:

```
Private Sub HTMLParser()

'This code will go to the html page and parse the page for the relevant data and put it into excel

'Select Cell A1 So Code Works As Intended
Range("A1").Select

'Declare variables
Dim ie As Object, i As Long, strText As String
Dim doc As Object, hTable As Object, hBody As Object, hTR As Object, hTD As Object
Dim tb As Object, bb As Object, tr As Object, td As Object
Dim y As Long, z As Long, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet

 Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
 Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 ie.Visible = True

  y = 1   'Column A in Excel
  z = 1   'Row 1 in Excel


'Enter Desired URL
 ie.navigate "MY URL HERE", , , , "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" & vbCrLf

'Wait until page fully loads
 Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
 Do While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

 Set doc = ie.document
 Set hTable = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")

'Loop through HTML Tags and paste every HTML table cell into excel
 For Each tb In hTable

    Set hBody = tb.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
    For Each bb In hBody

        Set hTR = bb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each tr In hTR


             Set hTD = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
             y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
             For Each td In hTD
               ws.Cells(z, y).Value = td.innerText
               y = y + 1
             Next td
             DoEvents
             z = z + 1
        Next tr
        Exit For
    Next bb
   Exit For
  Next tb
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried     "eggs" & "??????" & "and" & "?????" & "bacon".

Comment: I have not, I will give that a try! what do the ? marks do? and is there a reason there are 6 in the first one and 5 in the second?

Comment: ? Is any character. * is any number of characters. The number of ? Would set how many extra spaces you can handle.

Comment: Lets say your text is "eggs, beans and bacon" then "eggs" & "[star]" & "and" & "[star]" & "bacon" would return true while "eggs????and????bacon" would return false. The best way is probably to include spaces around the words, "eggs ????and ????bacon". Be careful not no force the text to include double spaced.  "eggs ???? and ???? bacon" would require two spaces between the words.